# HTML/PHP set value of option in select where I filled select from array

Tags: javascript, php, html, select

I am currently trying to set the value of an option in a select box from a php variable.

Just like a log in screen saves your username if you type the wrong password, I want to save the value of the option in the scroll box if something went wrong with submitting.

The problem arises now that I am using a script with an array to fill in the options in the select box. (PS have alot more choices, but cut down for example)

```
<script>
    var yrkeValg =
        [
            {
                "text"  : "Police",
                "value" : "police"
            },
            {
                "text"     : "Teacher",
                "value"    : "teacher"
            }
        ];

    var selectBox = document.getElementById('yrke');

    for(var i = 0, l = yrkeValg.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        var option = yrkeValg[i];
        selectBox.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected));
    }

</script>
```

I have tried to set the value from my php class function "hentYrke()", but it get's ignored. Have checked and the function value is correct.
How can I for example set teacher as the value from a php variable?

```
<select id="yrke" name="yrke" value="<?php $nyDeltaker->hentYrke() ?>"></select>
```

Comment: You line is missing `echo`, try this: `<?php echo $nyDeltaker->hentYrke() ?>`, read more about echo here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp

Comment: The options don't exist within the element when the page loads, that's your problem.

Comment: Does your Javascript live in the same file as your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `option`s of the `select` element don't exist on the page at page load, you need to add one more line to essentially "re-set" the value of the `select` element after they've been added.

```
<script>
    var yrkeValg =
        [
            {
                "text"  : "Police",
                "value" : "police"
            },
            {
                "text"     : "Teacher",
                "value"    : "teacher"
            }
        ];

    var selectBox = document.getElementById('yrke');

    for(var i = 0, l = yrkeValg.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        var option = yrkeValg[i];
        selectBox.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected));
    }

    // this is the line to add
    selectBox.value = document.getElementById('yrke').getAttribute('value');

</script>
```

[Demo using a hardcoded value of 'teacher'](https://jsfiddle.net/j4u3kguz/5/)

Note that depending on whether or not you are actually `echo`ing within your `hentYrek()` function, you may need to do as AamirR suggested.

Comment: Yes, while I forgot to add "echo" this time, I tried with it some of the other times. Your answer works perfect. Was trying something similiar with:
selectBox.value = "<?php echo $nyDeltaker->hentYrke() ?>"
But while I am still learning php and html I only came this far and was not quite sure why it wouldnt work. 
Thanks so much for the help!